# Django Serializers and Nested Objects

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am trying to deserialize and save an object from some JSON. 
I've got a couple object that looks like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):

  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=utcnow)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='items')


class Category(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
  description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=utcnow)
```

Now, I define serializers for these objects like this:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = EventCategory
    fields = (
      'id',
      'name',
      'description'
    )


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  created_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
  category = CategorySerializer()

  class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = (
      'id',
      'created_at',
      'category',
    )
```

What is a little funky about this data structuring is that the 'Category' objects need not be altered, and I don't want to create any new ones - I've pre-defined a bunch of these objects and they essentially express the 'type' of item we are dealing with. We won't be saving, updating, or adding new ones.

OK, now lets say I have a JSON representation of an Item that looks like this:

```
{'category': {'id': 1, 'name': 'some_name', 'description': 'some_description}, 'id': 101, 'created_at': date_info}
```

I would like create and save the Item object, but do not want to create a new category object. If I do this:

```
serializer = ItemSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
     serializer.save()
```

It complains that I am violating the unique=True constraint on the category's name field. I am assuming that the serializer is propagating the save operation to the category as well. My question: how can I define my serializers so that I can read out the category JSON when serializing, but so that I do not get this error when I am deserializing?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two serializers, one for each operation. Then, on your viewset, add a function that properly selects between them:

```
class StuffReadSerializer (...)
class StuffWriteSerializer (...)

class StuffViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Stuff

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return StuffReadSerializer
        return StuffWriteSerializer
```